# Excel - restrict to fixed text or integer length in the given range of cells

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, restrict, vba

1. How to make few range of cells to be restricted with fixed length in number of characters keying in.
2. How to make range of fields to be of Integer type alone. Meaning, it should not accept anything characters than Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use Data Validation.

From the Ribbon Data-> Data Validation.

You can restrict the selected cells to Whole Numbers,  Text Between min and max length, To a certain List, To Dates, etc.

[image]